# Готский язык - существовал?

Tags: языкознание

Словари часто ссылаются на ГОТСКИЙ язык.
Что это за язык такой?
Кто на нем говорил?
Почему нет словарей на этом языке?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы, Федя, хорошенько пороетесь в истории языкознания, то найдёте языки, от коих сохранилась лишь пара надписей на каменных стелах. Время не пощадило материальные носители, но если у нас нет источников для составления объёмистых тезаурусов, это ещё не значит, что не было и самого языка. О готах известно достаточно много хотя бы только по римским источникам, более того, в отличие от многих других народов, готы успели кое-что написать на своём языке, и из этого кое-чего сохранилось то, что более всего берегли и ценили: исторически первый перевод Библии на язык германцев, так называемая готская Библия Вульфилы. Сохранилась, к сожалению, не вся, список наличных фрагментов можно посмотреть здесь:
http://studopedia.net/7_35827_lektsiya---istoricheskie-svedeniya-o-gotah-gotskie-pismennie-pamyatniki.html
Это не так много, но всё-таки больше, чем пара надписей на камне, и позволило сделать достаточно много выводов о грамматическом строе языка, о ходе процессов развития германских языков, динамике изменений их фонетики в историческом процессе и прочая. То, что известно о о готском, включая реконструкции, изучается в курсе истории языка в рамках вузовской подготовки германистов.

Answer (score 1):

Таблица 1. Трансформация некоторых окончаний западного готского языка в современный русский язык: реконструкция восточного готского.

Готские окончания:

существительных: -a, - u, - am, - s, -r, -ar
прилагательных: -ar, -s
глаголов: -ai, - f, - n

Транзит в русский язык:

существительных: -a - аналогично, - u - аналогично, - am > амх, позднее выпадает м, - s > 1 ск 2 ский 3 инс, -r > редукция р, -ar > редукция р
прилагательных: -ar > 1 редукция р, арс позднее выпадает ар остается с 2 далее ск, ский , -s > ский
глаголов: -ai > аналогично , - f > 1 фе — е , далее ет 2 -й, - n > нт, позднее выпадает н

То есть: мама — мамар, на небесах — на небесамх, дай — даф, наш — наскар, ходит — ходиф, городской — городаск или городас и т.д.

Comment: Источник? Понаписать я такого могу.

Answer (score -1):

http://linguodiversity.narod.ru/Links/Ieulang/German/gothic.htm  и это все о нем.

Comment: Вы, вероятно, иронизировали.
Посмотрел я ВСЁ о готском языке.
И где же он?

В самом словаре ровно 180 слов. На букву "P", например, там всего 2 слова. А на букву К (тоже весьма распространенную в других языках) всего - 3 слова.

Это называется языком?


На каком основании это вообще можно считать языком, да еще и ссылать как на более древний при сравнительном анализе слов?


Заметьте, мы еще не проверяли сам состав этих 180 готских слов. Готские ли они, или относятся совсем к иной культуре?

Comment: Словарь streitberg1910  содержит 150 страниц по 30 в среднем слов на каждой.
Есть и англо-готский с не меньшим объемом.
Спешить - людей смешить. Вот и разбирайтесь, что там не так, а не так практически все. Часть слов - чистая реконструкция, подозрительные трудно произносимые окончания глаголов.
А вот такой перевод ставит вообще все в тупик  mainly  -- this-hun. главный.

Comment: Вы правы.Нахожу в указанном Вами словаре (http://www.wulfila.be/lib/streitberg/1910/html/B049.html) готское GIBA (горб), которое на деле является исконно русским корнем-основой ГИБ для следующих слов:ГНУТЬ сГИБать, выГИБать, БУГОР, ГРЕБень и др.

В самом латинской языке, первые признаки которого отмечены нами только в 15 веке, есть однокоренные GIBBA - горб, GIBBER - горбатый,
GIBBUS - горбун, выпуклый. 

В английском GIBBOSITY - горбатость. 
Испанское GIBA - горб, JOROBA - горб, JOROBADO - горбатый.

В словаре Фасмера, как водится, приведенного нами западно-европейского разнообразия не даётс

Comment: Зато есть такие "шедевры": Родственно лит. dvìgubas (двойной), trìgubas (тройной), gubá (копна хлеба), sugaubti (собрать хлеб), древне-верхне-немецкое goufana (пригоршня).


Не знаю КАК комментировать такое безобразие.

И при таких смысловых лакунах Фасмер еще осмеливается уводить своего читателя в сторону (!):
вопрос о родстве с... biegen "гнуть", др.-инд. bhujáti, греч. πτύσσω "складываю", πτυχή "складка" не является решенным.

Прелестно сказано - НЕ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ РЕШЕННЫМ!

Answer (score -1):

Русские и есть готы: то есть русский - дальнейшая эволюция готского.

Известно, что ряд филологов высказывали такую гипотезу. Например, по мере продвижения работы над этой гипотезой филологи Г. Шаль, а чуть позднее В.Н. Топоров пришли к выводу об изначальном единстве балтских, германских и славянских языков. Балто-славянский язык топонимики Восточной Германии в таком понимании получался практически «праславянским языком», а топонимы новгородской и псковской земли - «прагерманским языком».

(Топоров В.Н. О балтийских элементах в гидронимии и топонимии к западу от Вислы // Slavica Pragensia VIII, 1966; Топоров В.Н. О германских элементах в топонимики северной Руси // Slavica Pragensia VII, 1964.)

Б.А. Рыбаков считает, что славяне принадлежат к древнему индоевропейскому единству, в которое входят такие народы, как германские, иранские, кельтские, индийские, греческие и др. Одним из таких "кластеров" стали праславяне-прагерманцы, заселившие территорию от Среднего Поднепровья на востоке до Одера на западе, от северных склонов Карпат на юге до широты реки Припять на севере, чей язык не представляется возможным чётко дифференцировать.

Интересна гипотеза, согласно которой язык донских казаков является диалектом голдштийского. Так, например, слово  гутар, по всей видимости, готского происхождения. Древнее слово *любовь/любить* в гутаре  - *жадать/жалеть* имеет шведский или норвежский корень -*шалек/шарлетт* (любить).  В гутаре *кричать/плакать* - корень также имеется во многих западноевропейских языках: kriten, griten, готск., gransen, прусск., quarren нем., kry англ., clamate, лат., gråta шведск.

Ряд исследователей считает, что более корректно говорить о развитии восточных славянских языков больше из вандальского, нежели из готского, который в большей степени обладал синтетичностью, не подпадал под закон Гримма, стал основой для грамматического базиса русского, украинского и белорусского языков.

С сокращениями - [ИСТОЧНИК](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:bTbuEngrYUUJ:https://otvet.mail.ru/question/186829843%20&cd=2&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru).

Comment: Источник всего этого?

Comment: Вообще-то источник должен указывать автор, а не доброхот. Теперь не знаешь, кого за некорректности минусовать. Мое мнение - ахинея полная. Ну какая может быть "реконструкция" некорневых(!) морфов на основании слов, которых заведомо не было в реконструируемом языке?